# ImportError QtSql in Raspbian

Tags: sqlite, pyqt5, raspbian

QtSql import error occurs in Raspbian.
When I checked PyQt5 import in python console, it was imported.
Only QtSql Import Error occurred.
Anyone know how to fix?

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170124] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
>>> from PyQt5 import QtSql
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtSql'
```

Comment: execute: `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qtsql`

Answer (score 0):

It was solved by  eyllanesc help.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5.qtsql
```